# Escape Double Underscore and $ symbol with vanilla javascript using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, escaping, special-characters, selectors-api

I'm trying to target certain HTML tags generated by a framework, basically I'm trying to aim for the attributes and their values but since the framework auto generate them they have really weird naming. I can't target classes because there are multiple tags with the same class names.

In order to target this element:

```
<div class="jx_ui_html_div" __jx__id="___$_90__nav_bar">
```

I'm trying:

```
let chatNavBar = document.querySelectorAll('[__jx__id="___$_90__nav_bar"]')
```

When I console log "chatNavBar" I'm getting and empty object.

I know that i have to escape some characters on the attribute value and name but I just can't figure out how, any help will be really appreciate it.

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to aim here:

```js
let chatNavBar = document.querySelectorAll('[__jx__id="___$_90__nav_bar"]')
console.log("Selected Element:" + '' + JSON.stringify(chatNavBar))
```

```html
<div class="jx_ui_html_div" __jx__id="___$_90__nav_bar">
   <p>Hellow World</p>
<div>
```

Or on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/lowtrux/pen/mdVxNOV)

Comment: [Cannot reprocude](https://jsfiddle.net/n68d9mty/) -> Please add a [mcve]

Comment: @Andreas I have added a codepen.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` with a DOM object is almost never a good option...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: Or in your case: Replace `.querySelectorAll()` with `.querySelector()`

Answer (score -2):

The class of this element is just : "***jx_ui_html_div***"